# why sp returning error: subquery returned more than 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i am executing a procedure which returns error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I know because some fields are expected to return more then 1 values but i need to process it, i am working on Debit, credits subtraction result like CR-DR etc

```
(
   Conductor_ID
)
    Set @AccID= (Select Account_ID FROM Transport.Conductors WHERE ConductorID in (@ConductorID))
            Set @AccCredit= (Select CR from [dbo].[Transactions] where Account_ID in (@AccID))
            Set @AccDebit= (Select DR from [dbo].[Transactions] where Account_ID in (@AccID))
            Set @Total= @AccCredit-@AccDebit
```

Comment: once check the sub queries whether they are returning single or multiple rows

Comment: If there are multiple, which do you want to use?

Comment: You should use table variables or temp table if it is returning multiple values.

Comment: @PareshJ i am not much aware of sql , if you guys could help me, i did what i could, i don't understand how to do it :(

Comment: @TimSchmelter sir depends, may be all, if you are aware of finance i.e. debit credit etc

Comment: @AamirShah - A **variable** can hold only one value (ie) **one row**. But your sub-query is returning more than one row. So now which row you need to store in that variable. If you want to store more than one rows then use a temp table

Comment: yes sir, but how to get my final result i.e. CR-Dr etc, i am completely unaware @NoDisplayName

Answer (score 0):

try 
    use max() : it'll select the max value so there'll not be any multiple row selection confliction.

```
Set @AccID= (Select MAX(Account_ID) FROM Transport.Conductors WHERE         ConductorID in (@ConductorID))
        Set @AccCredit= (Select MAX(CR) from [dbo].[Transactions] where Account_ID in (@AccID))
        Set @AccDebit= (Select MAX(DR) from [dbo].[Transactions] where Account_ID in (@AccID))
        Set @Total= @AccCredit-@AccDebit
```

Comment: Here you are assigning the value to a variable so here it's necessary to return a single value from the sub query and  it's mandatory.

Comment: it's gonna give me unexpected results, i need to process all values bro

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong this is what you need

```
SELECT Account_ID,
       CR,
       DR,
       Total = CR - DR
FROM   [dbo].[Transactions] T
       JOIN Transport.Conductors C
         ON T.Account_ID = C.Account_ID
WHERE  C.ConductorID IN ( @ConductorID )
```

Comment: oh great, it works, but i am curious that how it works ? i mean this part Total = CR - DR

Comment: if u could explain then i will be grateful.